# NGINX Restrict endpoint or url to specific IP

Tags: nginx, permissions

I know the question seems kind of odd but let me explain what I am trying to achieve:
SCENARIO:
2 websites

```
green.com/endpoint  (Using NGINX)
red.com
```

Is there using any config in nginx, which lets me only accept connections coming from the host red.com only?

What green.com/endpoint should do is:

```
1. Analyze the request
2. If request comes from red.com -> ACCEPTED
    2.1 If request does not come from red.com -> REJECTED
```

***EDIT: (My Solution)***

Firstly edit your `conf.d/green.conf` file, to restrict any endpoint to a list of allowed IPs please consider:

`dig red.com`(or your allowed domain) and grab the public IP

```
       location ~* /endpoint {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:1234;
                #return 200 "$http_x_forwarded_for\n"; 
                set $allow false;
                if ($http_x_forwarded_for ~* 123.123.123.123) {
                set $allow true;
                }
                if ($allow = false) {
                return 403;
                }

       }
```

With this configuration, we only allow the domain **red.com** to access **green.com/endpoint**

Comment: Seems like you're looking for NGINX [rdns module](https://nginx-extras.getpagespeed.com/modules/rdns/).

Comment: Hi ! Maybe [here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/controlling-access-proxied-tcp/) ?

Comment: Hi @Philippe I updated with the solution that I implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to allow access to a specific ENDPOINT(URL) from specific DOMAIN(IP) is:

```
       location ~* /endpoint {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:1234;
            #return 200 "$http_x_forwarded_for\n"; 
            set $allow false;
            if ($http_x_forwarded_for ~* 123.123.123.123) {
            set $allow true;
            }
            if ($allow = false) {
            return 403;
            }

   }
```